# Is a check written in a language other than English valid?

Tags: united-states, check

If I wrote a check for $22.44, I would normally write "Twenty-two and 44/100". Would a bank accept the check if I wrote "Veintidós y 44/100" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bank is *allowed* to accept it, but it's also allowed to reject it. It's entirely at the discretion of the bank where the check is deposited.

As a practical matter, it's likely that a bank in Texas would accept a check in Spanish, but a bank in Maine might not.

Comment: I worked for a UK organisation and we sometimes got UK-bank cheques from North Americans living there who wrote "121.50" in the `£        ` box  but "one hundred and twenty one dollars and 50/100" and our bank processed them using the UKP value.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "the bank" you mean both the issuer (where the account is) and the clearer (where the deposit is being made), each of which needs to decide whether to accept or reject it

Comment: @littleadv - our bank means the bank providing our company's account. We scanned them in batches and sent them off to the the joint UK banks' regional clearing centre in Taunton once each week. The issuer's bank would generally only refuse for lack of funds. As a bulk cheque processor, we did the scrutiny, and if we accepted a cheque, the bank was good.

Comment: I heard from someone at that (big) organisation that if a cheque was otherwise OK but lacking a signature they were told they could find a pen the same colour as the sender's and just 'do a squiggle'. Likewise a missing item like payee, date, amount in figures or words could be 'put right'. Cheques were then batched up with a paper header slip and sent to 'the OCR room', where they were scanned and the OCR line (sender's account and bank code) data captured and saved into zip archives uploaded to the bank that day. All the cheques were the same amount.

Comment: I mean, who was going to complain that they had deliberately sent a void cheque? They would attract adverse attention from our compliance (!) people.